# Inserting Data in MS ACCES using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net and I want to store my data entries in MS ACCES but I get errors, I have checked my column names and tried the sql syntax in ms acces, the data I input there works but when I try it on vb.net it says I have Sysntax error in INSERT INTO.

Here is my code in inserting:

```
 Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click

    Try
        con.Open()
        sql = "INSERT INTO Register (LastName, Firstname, Adress, CellphoneNo, TelephoneNo, Email, PetName, Specie, Breed, Weight, Color, Gender, Age, DiagnosisType, When) VALUES ('" & LName.Text & "', '" & FName.Text & "', '" & Address.Text & "', '" & Val(CellNo.Text) & "', '" & Val(TelNo.Text) & "', '" & PetName.Text & "', '" & Specie.Text & "', '" & Breed.Text & "', '" & Val(Weight.Text) & "' , '" & Color.Text & "', '" & Gender.Text & "', '" & Val(Age.Text) & "', '" & Diagnosis.Text & "', '" & Val(Dates.Text) & "');"
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = sql

        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If i > 0 Then
            MsgBox("New record has been inserted successfully!")


        Else
            MsgBox("No record has been inserted successfully!")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
        loadrecord()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Additional question:
Do I have to use Val if the data type is a Number/currency?

Comment: What you are doing is considered poor practice, since it is vulnerable to SQL Injection (please take time to research this) and also inevitably leads to problems of the sort you are facing.  To deal with this you should use parameters instead.  In order to help you better, we need to know, what type your connection and command objects are.

Comment: I have only made this program for school purposes only, but soon I will research about security stuff. what do you mean by "what type of connection and command objects are"? I am sorry if I dont understand what you meant, I am dumb....

Comment: and by the way this is the tutorial I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d19592oQjdw

Comment: Your con and cmd variables are instances of a class.  What I am asking is which class? Are they OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand?

Comment: aahh I see, This is the connection I have 
CODE: 

Public Class RegisterClient
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Serafin\Documents\VetSystemDatabase.accdb")
    Dim sql As String
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

Comment: I have found the problem. the problem was the field name When. but there's a new problem and I do not know what it entirely means. the System says "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Comment: I have found the problem again I just neede to delete the single quotes on the one that has Val